# TypeError: 'AutoTrackable' object is not callable

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to run inference on my trained model following this [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/inference_from_saved_model_tf2_colab.ipynb). I am using TF 2.1.0 and I have tried with tf-nightly 2.5.0.dev20201202.
But I get `TypeError: 'AutoTrackable' object is not callable` when I hit the following line `detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)`
I am aware that
['AutoTrackable' object is not callable in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471873/autotrackable-object-is-not-callable-in-python)
exists but I am not using tensorflow hub and I don't understand how the answer could help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using `detect_fn.signatures\['default'](input_tensor)`

Answer (score 1):

Changing `detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)` to
`detections = detect_fn.signatures['serving_default'](input_tensor)`
fixed the issue for me.